# Given a string A and a set of string S. Need to find an optimum method to find a prefix of A which is not a prefix of any of the strings in s

Tags: string, algorithm

Example

```
A={apple}

S={april,apprehend,apprehension}
```

Output should be "appl" and not app since app is suffix of both "apple" and "apprehension" but "appl" is not.

I tried to do this by finding the longest common prefix of A with every string in S and then the answer will be the longest of these prefixes. But this method takes a lot of time since A is also a part of a set of strings and I have to do this for all such strings.

Please suggest an optimum approach.

Comment: How is your set S defined? Can you modify it? One solution would be to create a tree structure with your set S (one character by node) and walk down this tree.

Comment: Btw. the data structure @fharreau is suggesting is known as a trie.

Comment: @fharreau Set S is a vector of strings.

Comment: @AyushGoyal So you need to create a `trie` from this vector. Did not know about its name (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) just remember my lessons time toying with a T9 simulator :D.

Comment: @fharreau So should I create trie from S or from the set of strings of which A is a part , or both ?

Comment: You create the trie from S set. Then foreach string in A's set, walk down the trie. Look at @Ambika answer. He explains it better than me :D.

Answer (score 1):

As you only ask for an optimum approach, here it is:

You need to create a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) from your vector S and then walk down the tree, character by character from your string A.

It will be much more efficient than your first approach.

If you need help for implementing this approach, you can ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Trie data structure here.

```
Insert all strings in Set S in trie

now traverse string A in trie in dfs manner

        You will get your prefix, when you'll get null during 
        traversal
```

I am taking a short example for better view.

Let say A = "rama";
and B  {"shy","raku","rio"}

Now after first trie become like below

```
               ROOT
          /     |  
        s       r    
      /      /     \
     h       a      i
    /      /       /
   y      k       o
         /  
        u
```

Now in second step traverse "ramu" in dfs manner, we'll get null on reaching 'm' of string "ramu"

So "ram" is required answer.

Comment: Now let's say another string in A's set is ramu. Since it has been found that ram is acceptable prefix for rama , is there a way to find acceptable prefix for ramu without traversing the trie again since ram is also an acceptable prefix for ramu?

Comment: No, you have to traverse that string too on trie and by the way in question you have mentioned A is string not set

Comment: Actually I mentioned in the end of the question that A is also part of a set of string. That is why I thought we could improve by memoizing the previous solutions , like ram for rama and ramu.

Comment: But if you have "jaya" in set A. Then, what do

Comment: @fharreau Are you sure ? I think if it is `ram` for `ramu` it will be the case for `rama` too since the trie algorithm will necessary return null on the `m` too

Comment: That's right. I misread the example. I've deleted my comment.